# Inserting multiple record with array

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form which is used to insert data in mysql.My form field details are 
    1.username
    2.number of sample
    3.sampleid
    4.Sample location.
     Sample id and sample location are multiple record depending upon the value of number of sample.i want to save these record to my table on click on button.I have declared sample id and sample location as array.but when i am inserting these data using for loop the number of record are saved as per no of sample but the value in sampleid and sample location are not getting saved only text "array" is saved instead of input value.

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/config.php');
if(strlen($_SESSION['alogin'])==0)
    {   
header('location:index.php');
}
else{ 

if(isset($_POST['add']))
    {

$samplecount=$_POST['samplecount'];
$user=$_POST['user'];       
$samplelocation=$_POST['samplelocation'];
$sampleid=$_POST['sampleid'];

$sql="INSERT INTO  tblfacility(user,samplelocation,sampleid) VALUES(:user,:samplelocation,:sampleid)";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':user',$btr,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':samplelocation',$facility,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':type',$sampleid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
}
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div class="form-group">
<label>user name.<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="user"  required="required" autocomplete="off" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>no of sample<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="samplecount"  required="required" autocomplete="off" />
</div>  
</div>

<table   class="table table-striped small-text" id="tb" >
<tr class="tr-header">
<h4 style="color:darkGreen;" ><b><u>SAMPLE id</u></b></h4> 
<th  class= "col-md-2" align="centre">Sample Location</th>
<th><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:18px;" id="addMore" title="Add More Sample"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></th>


<tr>
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=1;$i++)
{   
?>

<td><input type="text"  name="sampleid[]"class="form-control" ></td> 
<td><input type="text" name="samplelocation[]" class="form-control" ></td>

<td><a href='javascript:void(0);'  class='remove'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>
<?php }?>
</tr>
</table>
<button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-info"  align="middle" >ADD </button>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#addMore').on('click', function() {
              var data = $("#tb tr:eq(1)").clone(true).appendTo("#tb");
              data.find("input").val('');

     });
     $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
         var trIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
            if(trIndex>1) {
             $(this).closest("tr").remove();
           } else {
             alert("Sorry!! Can't remove first row!");
           }
      });
}); 

</script>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    </div>


    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
     <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<?php } ?>
```

it is not saving the array vaue.it is saving "array" in all field

Comment: This is a terrible idea (I'm sure we've mentioned this before). Just let mysql handle the ids.

Comment: @Strawberry code has been edited  kindly guide me